# Snap to grid using knife tool

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms, snapping, knife-tool

I have a situation where, after extruding an angled face, I need to make an edge of it flush with the grid lines. I tried to illustrate what I want to do with the image below. Note, the new location does not lie along the intersections of the grid, only along the X line, so I cannot use snap to grid.

[image: example object with cut marked]

I believe the best way to accomplish this would be with the knife tool, but I need a way to snap it to the grid in order to get accurate results. Is there such an option? Bisect would also work.

I am aware I could use a second object and intersect them to get this result, but I would prefer if a tool could accomplish what I need, as my current project will involve a lot of this.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited)

1. Snap a 3D cursor anywhere on that X line you need.
2. Create a new plane.
3. Press R to rotate, then X to lock to X axis and rotate a plane so it would be intersecting your figure.
4. Go to modifiers tab and add boolen modifier.
5. Select your figure as an object.
6. Apply a modifier.

It should create a vertice on the intersection that you can use with snap tool.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, at least in my version, as intended. It snaps to the edge, but ANY point along the edge, not just the intersection with the X-line. The vertex only moves along X... but not to the desired position, because the snapping point moves freely along the edge. Picture of the result: http://i.imgur.com/NYQcgjO.png

Comment: You are right, that way didn't work, I've edited the post. Now it works with planes but I'm not sure if it will work with complex geometry.